# Как обратиться к произвольному контроллеру из другого контроллера

Tags: laravel

Делаю проект: отдельно фронт на вью, отдельно бэк на ларавеле - rest API. Операции CRUD все работает замечательно. Стал реализовывать построение отчетов. Создал в ларавеле контроллер, в нем метод CreateReport, который возвращает pdf во фронт. В него передаю оттуда id строки таблицы, название модели. Как обратиться к контроллеру по его строковому названию, что бы вызвать метод show? В интернетах сразу ругаются, что вызов метода котроллера из другого контроллера это антипаттерн, как же быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного запутался в вашем вопросе что и откуда вызывает. Предлагаю Вам сделать как-то так. 
Как я понял Вы указываете id строки в определённой таблице и название этой таблицы(модели) и делаете pdf на основе данных. 
Тем самым Вы можете указать любую таблицу и он сделает pdf выгрузку. Значит вывод такой что метод `createReport` внутри работает с абстрактными данными, так как у всех таблиц разные поля и метод не привязан с структуре. Поэтому предлагаю создать `trait` например Reports.
в нем указать метод `createReport` и другие которые относятся к отчётам. И далее подключаете его в те модели которые должны собирать отчётность:

```
class News extends Model
{
    use Reports;
    //Остальная логика модели
    ...
}
```

В результате каждая модель будет иметь метод `createReport` в своём арсенале!

(Метод show в таком виде для примера, название модели можете передавать в любом виде, хоть создавая контроллеры отчётов под каждую модель в отдельности. Снизу просто для наглядности пример).

```
class ReportsController extends Controller 
{
   ...
   public function show($id, $nameModel)
   {
       $className = "\App\$nameModel";
       $model = $className::find($id);
       return $model->createReport();
   }
   ...
}
```

Либо второй вариант. Создайте фасад `Reports` и делайте так:

```
class ReportsController extends Controller 
{
   ...
   public function show($id, $nameModel)
   {
       return Reports::createReport($id, $nameModel);
   }
   ...
}
```

В результате создавать контроллеры в контроллере не придётся.